# Back button does not work correctly with NavOptions setPopUpTo

Tags: android, kotlin

I have fragment with list of notes. When user clicks on a note, they open fragment with note page. I use navigation UI and NavOptions to navigate:

```kotlin
    fun toNotePage() {
        val navOptions: NavOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
            .setPopUpTo(R.id.navigation_notes, true, true)
            .setRestoreState(true)
            .build()

        findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_note_page, null, navOptions)
    }
```

At first I used `.setPopUpTo(R.id.navigation_notes, false, true)`, with "inclusive" param false. That time I pressed on the note, note page fragment opened correctly, but back button didn't work. Than I changed "inclusive" param to true, and back button worked in the note page fragment, but only once. When I return with back button to notes list and than click on the note once more, I navigate to note page fragment, but back button stops working. And system back button closes application insteam of opening notes list.

UPD: this code worked well, with "inclusive" "false":

```kotlin
    fun toNotePage() {
        val navOptions: NavOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
            .setPopUpTo(R.id.navigation_notes, false, true)
            .setRestoreState(true)
            .build()

        findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_note_page, null, navOptions)
    }
```

And this code also worked well:

```kotlin
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_notes_to_navigation_note_page)
```

Problem was I was redirected every time I returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a navigation issue at all. I just used StateFlow to trigger navigation after list item clicked, but I did not update it correctly. So I did return to notesFragment, but I was always redirected to note page once more.

https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the default behavior but confusing the system with adding navOptions. Just delete them and only use single line:

```
    fun toNotePage() {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_note_page)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is working good, and NavOptions with ```.setPopUpTo(R.id.navigation_notes, false, true)``` also worked good. The problem was that I use MVVM + StateFlow (https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events), but really forgot to update state, so I was redirected each time I returned.